# JQuery UI dialog cannot load page content dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog, dynamic

I have used a tutorial http://www.devcurry.com/2010/06/load-page-dynamically-inside-jquery-ui.html to dynammically load an aspx page into a jquery ui dialog without using an iframe

eg.

```
$(function() {
        $('<div>').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            open: function() {

                $(this).load('Example.aspx');




            },
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
        });
```

When I debugged this page it just loading a blank dialog box with none of the content in even though the page has content. I have written it with the paths

eg `$(this).load('/Home/Example.aspx');`

I have even added in a function to check if it is loading

eg `$(this).load('/Home/Example.aspx', function(){alert(Load Successful);});` which does return true YET still no content in the dialog

I am using Jquery 1.3.2 an ui 1.7.3 with ASP.Net Mvc

I know there are lots of questions/answers on this topic on stackoverflow but none of them seem to be successfully answering my problem and as these questions seem a year old not sure whether someone will get back to me asap.

Any ideas on showing the content in the dialog

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is...

```
$(function() {
        $('<div></div>').hide().load('Home/Example #content_form', function() {
        $(this).dialog({

                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                height: 400,
                width: 400,
                title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
            })

        })
```

With Example.aspx having a  tag with ID = content_form

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, try changing your selector to

```
$('<div></div>').dialog({
```

Also the example you cited is using jquery 1.4.2 and jquery ui 1.8.1, 
can you upgrade?

Edit:
You could also try it this way.

```
$(function() {
    $('<div></div>').load('Example.aspx', {}, 
        function(data) {})
        .dialog(
        {
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
        }).dialog('open');
    });
```

Note I haven't tested this, but its the way I do it. Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: had tried the divs didn't change the anything plus the load method has been around in jquery since the very beginning and hasn't been changed. I think the problem is I'm opening the dialog before the page contents have loaded and display is somehow set to false

Comment: As a test, specify a visible div in your html and try using jquery.load to load the div. If you can see the content, the ajax load is working properly. If not you may have a problem with actually getting the response back from the server. If you get content, then at least you've narrowed down the problem. Also which browser(s) have to tested against?